# IMPRIMIR TODOS LOS REGISTROS DE UN INNER JOIN

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problemita y no hallo corregir el error... cuento con este codigo PHP mostrado a continuacion, en el cual hago un inner join y lo que quiero hacer es jalar todos los resultados de los registros obtenidos por medio de un array para lograr imprimirlos de manera de lista

Lo intente de dos maneras una esta comentada sin embargo ninguna de las dos maneras funciona correctamente... Ojala puedan ayudarme... SALUDOS Y MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!!

```
    $consulta = "SELECT a.numero_proveedor AS NUMERO_PROVEDOR,a.monto_pago AS MONTO_PAGO,a.fecha_archivo AS FECHA_ARCHIVO,pf.nombre AS NOMBRE,pf.apellido_paterno AS APELLIDO_PATERNO,pf.apellido_materno AS APELLIDO_MATERNO,pf.razon_social AS RAZON_SOCIAL,pf.sucursal AS SUCURSAL,pf.cuenta AS CUENTA,pf.clabe AS CLABE,tf.descripcion AS TIPO_TRANSFERENCIA,b.nombre AS BANCO,d.descripcion AS ESTATUS
FROM tef.archivo a

INNER JOIN tef.proveedores pf ON a.numero_proveedor = pf.numero_proveedor
INNER JOIN tef.tipo_transferencia tf ON pf.id_tipo_transferencia = tf.id
INNER JOIN tef.bancos b ON pf.id_banco = b.id
INNER JOIN tef.estatus_proveedor d ON pf.id_estatus = d.id";
// where b.id=1

$rs = mysql_query ( $consulta)or die (mysql_error()); 
$row5 = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

    $monto             = $row5["MONTO_PAGO"];
    $clabe             = $row5["clabe"];
    $cuenta_prov       = $row5["CUENTA"];
    $nombre            = $row5["nombre"];
    $apellido_paterno  = $row5["apellido_paterno"];
    $apellido_materno  = $row5["apellido_materno"];
    $tipo_transferencia= $row5["TIPO_TRANSFERENCIA"];
    $sucursal          = $row5["SUCURSAL"];


// while ($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    // echo $row6[1];
    // echo $row6[2];
    // echo $row6[3];
    // echo $row6[4];
    // echo $row6[5];

    // }
```

Comment: ¿Qué version de PHP estás usando?, si es la v. 7, tu código no funcionará, dado que la extensión `mysql_*` no existe más en PHP 7. Aunque tengas la versión 5, conviene pasar tu código a `mysqli` o a `PDO`, si es posible.

Comment: No deberías usar el grupo de funciones mysql_* pues ya son obsoletas e inseguras te recomiendo PDO

Comment: no debe utilizar la extesion mysql_* esta obsoleta, debe  usar MySQLI  o PDO_MySQL para conectarse a mysql

Comment: Hola chicos gracias antes que nada a todos pr su recomendacion, pero utilizo la version 4 de PHP , se que es obsoleta pero es la que la empresa me permite. Ya que por politicas de ellos no es posible actualizar por el momento...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que, como dices, no tienes por ahora alternativa para migrar a mysqli o a PDO, propongo el siguiente código.

El mismo irá controlando el flujo, recogiendo los eventuales resultados en una variable llamada `$arrOutput`, la cual podrás usar al final para imprimir los mensajes de error o un array con los datos.

Fíjate que yo he usado [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php). Esta función te crea un arreglo asociativo con los resultados, y en el `while` no estarás obligada a nombrar cada columna de forma explícita, pues `fetch_assoc` ya se encarga de asignar a cada valor su nombre de columna.

Este sería el código:

```
$arrOutput=array(); 
$consulta = "SELECT 
                    a.numero_proveedor AS NUMERO_PROVEDOR,
                    a.monto_pago AS MONTO_PAGO,
                    a.fecha_archivo AS FECHA_ARCHIVO,
                    pf.nombre AS NOMBRE,
                    pf.apellido_paterno AS APELLIDO_PATERNO,
                    pf.apellido_materno AS APELLIDO_MATERNO,
                    pf.razon_social AS RAZON_SOCIAL,
                    pf.sucursal AS SUCURSAL,
                    pf.cuenta AS CUENTA,
                    pf.clabe AS CLABE,
                    tf.descripcion AS TIPO_TRANSFERENCIA,
                    b.nombre AS BANCO,
                    d.descripcion AS ESTATUS
             FROM tef.archivo a
             INNER JOIN tef.proveedores pf ON a.numero_proveedor = pf.numero_proveedor
             INNER JOIN tef.tipo_transferencia tf ON pf.id_tipo_transferencia = tf.id
             INNER JOIN tef.bancos b ON pf.id_banco = b.id
             INNER JOIN tef.estatus_proveedor d ON pf.id_estatus = d.id";
// where b.id=1
$rs = mysql_query($consulta);  //Aquí había un error  .... si no funciona, pásale un segundo parámetro con la variable de conexión: $rs = mysql_query($consulta,$variableConexion);

if (!$rs) {
    $arrOutput["error"]="No se pudo ejecutar la consulta. Error: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($rs) == 0) {
    $arrOutput["error"]="No se encontraron registros";
}else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
        $arrOutput[]=$row;    
    }
    mysql_free_result($rs); 

}

/*
    *Ocurra lo que ocurra, habrá datos en $arrOutput
    *los cuales podrás imprimir convenientemente
    *el print_r es sólo para ver lo que hay dentro
*/
    print_r($arrOutput);
```

Comment: Cedano muchas gracias!! pero ahora no me imprime nada :S   me aparece la plantilla en blanco. 

al final le puse un 

echo $arrOutput pero ni asi muestra los regristros... Sera que algo hice mal ?

Comment: El  `echo $arrOutput;` no te imprimirá nada, porque la variable es un array. Ponlo como está en la respuesta: `print_r($arrOutput);`, o, mejor así: `var_dump($arrOutput);` Revisando mejor el código, aquí hay un error: `$rs = mysql_query($sql);` debería ser: `$rs = mysql_query($consulta);`, si aún así no funciona, entonces la función necesita un segundo parámetro, que sería la variable de la conexión: `$rs = mysql_query($consulta,$variableDeConexion);`, claro está que en lugar de `$variableDeConexion` debes poner el nombre que le das a dicha variable. @karinareyes